# Sublime Text remember open files and folders

Tags: sublimetext

All I want to do is make it so that way every time I open Sublime Text, it opens all of the files and folders that I was working on before, as opposed to me manually opening the same folders and files every time I open Sublime Text.

For example, after I close a window, the next time I open Sublime Text, I expect the same window to be opened; almost as if it was never closed.

Many thanks.

P.S. 'hot_exit' and 'remember_open_files' are both set as true under Preferences > Settings - Default.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The things you've done should do what you're wanting, so let's re-inspect some of the basics:

With `"hot_exit": true` present in your settings, Sublime Text will not ask to save changes to files when exiting; it will just exit. Any open and/or changed files will open back up when Sublime Text does starts.

The `"remember_open_files": true` setting doesn't do anything if `"hot_exit": true`.
If `"hot_exit": false` and `"remember_open_files": true`, Sublime Text will prompt when closing unsaved changes, and re-open the files on startup.

So the settings you need are:

```
...
"hot_exit": false,
"remember_open_files": true,
...
```

Make sure that the settings are exactly as above, with `"` surrounding the setting, no quoting surrounding the value, a `:` separating them, and a comma at the end of the line unless it's the last line in the setting file.

If this setting isn't working for you in `Preferences > Settings - Default`, try it in `Preferences > Settings - User`.

Comment: Thanks for that, I also realised that because I'm using a Mac, even when I closed the last window, I'm not closing the application, so all I was doing was requesting a blank window.

Comment: Kurtiss, that too is an option. that is, close_windows_when_empty

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for the answer to the question in the TITLE 
ie: how to set the default folder  Sublime opens when 'Open Folder' is used, try this:
[Link to similar question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/613711/is-there-a-plugin-for-default-file-location-in-sublime-text-2)