# How to open default project in Sublime Text when starting app (mac)

Tags: macos, sublimetext2

When I click the sublime text icon (to start/open it) I would like it to default to either a specific folder, or the last folder that was open. This SO question was helpful:

[Set Sublime Text's default directory when opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709834/set-sublime-texts-default-directory-when-opened)

However I have set hot_exit, remember_open_files, and close_windows_when_empty and none of this seems to work for me.

If I actually 'quit' sublime text down in the dock, then it will open the last project I had open (in addition to another blank window).

Any way to make it remember my project without having to quit the app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I set `hot_fix`, `remember_open_files`, and `close_windows_when_empty` as described in [Set Sublime Text's default directory when opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709834/set-sublime-texts-default-directory-when-opened), and this works on macOS **IF** you 'quit' sublime rather than closing the app using the 'x' in the upper right hand corner of the app. So for me, when I want to close sublime I go down in the doc and right click on sublime and choose 'quit', and when I open it again, the last project I had open will be displayed.

Another quick option is to use command-q to quit the app.

Comment: I don't see the `remember_open_files` setting in Version 3.0 Build 3143 on Windows 10 Pro via `Preferenes > Settings`.